# NodeJS and storing OAuth credentials, outside of the code base?

Tags: node.js, oauth

I am creating a NodeJS API server that will be delegatiing authentication to an oauth2 server. While I could store the key and secret along with the source code, I want to avoid doing that since it feels like a security risk and it is something that doesn't match the lifespan of a server implementation update (key/secret refresh will likely happen more often).

I could store it in a database or a maybe a transient json file, but I would like to know what are the considered the best practices in the NodeJS world or what is considered acceptable. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to provide something that can store multiple values, I just created a JSON file and then read that into a module I called keystore (using ES6 class):

```
class KeyStore {

  load() {
     // load the json file from a location specified in the config
     // or process.env.MYSERVER_KEYSTORE
  }

  get (keyname) {
     // return the key I am looking for
  }

}

module.exports = new KeyStore();
```

I would ideally want to store the file encrypted, but for now I am just storing it read only to the current user in the home directory.

If there is another way, that is considered 'better', then I am open to that.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set environment variables as part of your deployment and then access them in the code from the global [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) object:

```
var clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID
var clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
```